# insert array to moongose using angular and node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js

I have a problem I using mlab(mongoose) , angular.js, html , javascript.
When I pass array with values from angular.js controller to server side (node.js)
its not working .. it does not insert the data into my schema in mlab

this this my html code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/addPersonal">
    <tags-input ng-model="Tags" name="Tags"></tags-input>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clickme()">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

my controller in angular.js (client side):

```
mymedical.controller('insertPersonalCtrl',

    ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){   

            $scope.clickme = function(){  
                    var data = {};      
                    data.Tags = $scope.Tags;     
                $http.post('http://localhost:3000/addPersonal', data).then()
            }                
    }]);
```

my controller in server side (node.js):

```
 var savePersonal = new personal({
                Tags:request.body.Tags
              });
          savePersonal.save(function(error, result) {}
```

schema:

```
var privateSchema = new schema({
  Tags : []
},{collection: 'personal'});
```

what do I need to do?
Thanks,

Comment: can you please post the error log?

Comment: from your code i can see you are not checking for errors. Please modify to log errors.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/addPersonal. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @adi so you not set cors of the node server

Comment: @KxngKombian thanks for your answer! can you explain what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

so you need to set a cors middleware on the nodejs server.

CORS allows web scripts to interact more openly with content outside of the original domain.

a good package will be https://github.com/expressjs/cors